# Unable to add WINE repository for Mint 19

Tags: apt, software-installation, repository, wine

I am following the instructions on the wineHQ website to install the package. I run into problems on the following step.

> On Linux Mint 19.x, the last line should be the following:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/**ICON**bionic main'
> ```

That space is created by a hyperlink icon. I have tried a few permutations of the line above and I always get back

```
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/bionic 
   bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is
therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
```

I am not sure what the proper address should be for the repository.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) instructions:

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
```

I'm not familiar with Mint, but since it's based on Ubuntu it should work.